# How do I Join on NULL values in Contour?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

I need to join two datasets in Contour on a column that contains NULLs.

Contour drops NULLs when performing joins, but in this case, it's important to match the NULLs across this dataset. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to the Join, use an Expression board to replace the NULL values in the desired column with some non-NULL string value, such as "null". Repeat this for your second dataset, possibly via creating a new path in your Contour analysis with your second dataset as an input. Then the Join between these two datasets will work as desired.